# Which is the best way to find max and min of this function: $f(x,y)=\frac{x^6+y^4}{x^3+xy^2}$?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

[image]

> Function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^6+y^4}{x^3+xy^2}$ on the domain $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^3; x>0, y\ge0\}$.

The answer for the problem is that the function doesn't have max or min. My first try was to calculate the gradient and see when it is equal to $0$. For me solving the system requires too much time, so is there a faster method? Can I use the domain given to answer the problem?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that solving the system isn't as hard as you think it is. $\frac{\partial f }{\partial y}=\frac{2y\left(-x^6+2x^2y^2+y^4\right)}{x\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$ (once we have simplified $\frac{4y^3\left(x^3+xy^2\right)-2xy\left(x^6+y^4\right)}{\left(x^3+xy^2\right)^2}$), so if we want to solve $\frac{\partial f }{\partial y}=0$ for $y$, then we can quite easily using the basic rules of algebra find that $y=0$. However, if we substitute this into $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \:x}$ (which is $\frac{3x^8+5x^6y^2-3x^2y^4-y^6}{\left(x^3+xy^2\right)^2}$), then we get $\frac{3x^8}{x^6}=0$, which means that $x=0$. This is not in the domain of $f(x,y)$. Therefore, a maximum, minimum or saddle point does not exist. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's worth trying some typical parameters from the domain like $(x,0)$, $(0,y)$, $(x,x)$ or $(x,-x)$. Here you can calculate:
$f(x,0) = x^3$. We see that this is unbounded from the above and arbitrarily close to zero. Since $f(x,y)>0$ for all $(x,y)$ we see that $f$ doesn't have minimum nor maximum.

Comment: $(0,y)$ is not in the domain. (But we can look at $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x,y)$)

Comment: @aschepler My comment about points (x,0), (0,y) and so on was general. I used 'sometimes'. These are points (or paths towards zero) I consider to quickly determine the behaviour of the function near 0 and, as here, also check boundedness of a function.